# d3.js if else regex string match to change style

Tags: javascript, regex, d3.js

I have the following string in a column(col2) in a csv file:

```
  "unserer {m}, unsere {p} and {f}, unseres {n}
```

I would like to color the background of the words preceeding {m|f|n} based on the value in { }. ( m stands for male, f for female, n for neuter )

This, I would like to match strings and change their style and am looking for the correct syntax. I have tried filter, but was not successful to implement multiple filters

```
  d3.select("#sentence").html(
      if ( d.col2.match(/.*\w+\s\{f\}/) ) {
            this.style("background-color","red")
      } else {
            this.style("background-color","blue")
      };
      );
```

Thus I am looking for the correct way of writing this code.

```
  d3.select("#sentence").html(d.col2).filter(function () {
      if ( d.col2.match(/.*\w+\s\{f\}/) ) {
            this.style("background-color","red")
      } else {
            this.style("background-color","blue")
      };
      };);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d3.select("#sentence").html(d.col2)
    .style({ "background-color": "blue" })
    .filter(function () {
        return d.col2.match(/.*\w+\s\{f\}/)
    })
    .style({ "background-color": "red" })
```

---

If you actually want to style the paragraphs and set their content and then the styles, it would be better to use classes instead of id. So something like

```
<div class="sentence"></div>
<div class="sentence"></div>
```

would have the script as

```
d3.selectAll(".sentence").data(d).html(function (d) {
        return d.col2
    })
    .style("background-color", function(d) {
        if ( d.col2.match(/.*\w+\s\{f\}/) ) {
            return "red"
        } else {
            return "blue"
        };
    });
```

If you actually want to style the paragraphs

```
d3.selectAll(".sentence").data(d).html(function (d) {
        return d.col2
    })
    .style("background-color", function(d) {
        if ( d.col2.match(/.*\w+\s\{f\}/) ) {
            return "red"
        } else {
            return "blue"
        };
    });
```

with the data d as

```
var d = [
    {
        col2: "your data"
    },
    {
        col2: "more of your data"
    },
    {
        col2: "and here's some more"
    }
]
```

Comment: Your code works - thank you very much. I will apply it. Now, I have a subset of strings that is more complicated, example: 'unserer {m}, unseren {f}, unsere {n}'. I would like to color the word preceding {m|f|n} based on the {m},  {f} or {n} flag. I assume that I have to split these string first ?

Comment: Yes to your previous comment, you have to have a separate tag for coloring only that part.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have data bound to the element with `id` of `sentance`.  If so, it's as simple as:

```
 d3.select('#sentance')
    .style("background-color", function(d){
      return d.col2.match(/.*\w+\s\{f\}/) ? "red" : "blue";
    });
```

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="sentance">Now is the winter of our discontent.</div>
    <script>
      d3.select('#sentance')
        .datum({col2: "somestring"})
        .style("background-color", function(d){
          return d.col2.match(/.*\w+\s\{f\}/) ? "red" : "blue";
        })
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: is there a way to write the datum line different ?