# Wildcard selection on SVG attribute using D3.JS Library

Tags: jquery, d3.js

The following is an svg path tag extracted from an svg file:

```
<path id="GOR-SK;06;06-G4-0708" d="M50431.61,-2196.75l- 
1912.93,0l0,302.8l0,1137.2l1912.93,0z" class="selectable"
</path>
```

I am trying to lookup all path elements containing the string "06-G4-708" from the id attribute.

I am using D3.Js to do this but unfortunately I have not found the correct syntax yet.

What I have done so far is :

```
 d3.selectAll('path').classed('lime', d => d.id.indexOf('06-G4-708') >= 0);
```

This is throwing the following error message : [variable d not defined.]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use regular expression to filter your selection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626939/d3-js-if-else-regex-string-match-to-change-style?rq=1.

Comment: look in the devtools and inspect the `path` elements and see if they have an `__data__` key. How do you construct these paths, they should contain the attached datum, I checked with the blocks examples.

Comment: you can try `d3.selectAll('path').classed('lime', function () {d3.select(this).attr('id').indexOf('06-G4-708') >= 0 });`

Comment: Closely related if not duplicate: [*"Wildcard selection on SVG attribute using D3.JS Library"*](/q/52317106). The only thing you might need to change is to use the `*=` attribute selector to look for an occurence anywhere inside the string instead of `^=` which will look for a match at the beginning of the attribute's value.